# What can I do to add correct Pinterest TAG on website

Tags: php, html, tags, dom-events, pinterest

I have a problem with the Pinterest TAG.
I added the code and marked the add to cart button.

Standard code:

```
<!-- Pinterest Tag -->
<script>
!function(e){if(!window.pintrk){window.pintrk = function () {
window.pintrk.queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))};var
n=window.pintrk;n.queue=[],n.version="3.0";var
t=document.createElement("script");t.async=!0,t.src=e;var
r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
r.parentNode.insertBefore(t,r)}}("https://s.pinimg.com/ct/core.js");
pintrk('load', 'MY_ID', {em: '<user_email_address>'});
pintrk('page');
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt=""
src="https://ct.pinterest.com/v3/?event=init&tid=MY_ID&pd[em]=hashhed_email_adress&noscript=1" />
</noscript>
<!-- end Pinterest Tag -->
```

Add to cart button:
`<button onclick="pintrk('track', 'addtocart');" class="addtobasket btn btn-red" type="submit">`

In the Pinterest panel, I have information about the lack of a product ID. What do I have to do to add the currency or the purchase amount to the add to cart button? My guess is that I should write something in Javascript. If I add anything to the button code line, it crashes the page.